# Printing a specific pattern in C Programming using for loops

Tags: c

Hi I need some help figuring out how to write this pattern program.  The console asks for a number of rows and prints out an ascending triangle made out of stars where each proceeding line has two more stars than the previous one, then a descending triangle where each proceeding line has two less stars than the previous one.  That probably wasn't the best explanation but here is an example of what I essentially need to get:

Enter number of rows: 6

```
*
***
*****
*****
***
*
```

Another example with odd number:

Enter number of rows: 7

```
*
***
*****
*******
*****
***
*
```

I've been looking for this specific example on forums but I've yet to find it

Comment: have you tried something to show us?

Comment: There are a number of similar questions around SO, printing various variations on the theme — pyramids, Christmas trees, etc.

Answer (score 2):

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int rows;
    int limit;
    int twiceFlag = 0;
    char c = '*';
    int i,j;
    printf("enter the number of rows:");
    scanf("%d", &rows);

    if (rows % 2 == 0){
        twiceFlag = 1;
        limit = rows / 2;
    }
    else{
        limit = rows / 2 + 1;
    }

    /*Logic to print the Stars*/
    for (i = 1; i <= limit; i++){
        printf("%c", c);
        for (j = 1; j < i; j++){
            printf("%c%c", c, c);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    if (twiceFlag == 1){
        printf("%c", c);
        for (j = 1; j < limit; j++){
            printf("%c%c", c, c);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    limit -=2;
    for (i = limit; i >= 0; i--){
        printf("%c", c);
        for (j = i; j > 0; j--){
            printf("%c%c", c, c);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `main()` doesn't use either `argc` or `argv`, it is best to use `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
int main(){    
    int row=6,n;                //enter number of rows
    n=row/2;
    for(int i=n; i>=-n;i--)    //if row is 6, `i` will work for 3 to -3
    {
        if(row%2==0 && i==0)    //if number is even, shouldn't work for i=0
            i--;
        for(int j=1; j<=(2*(n-(i<0?-i:i)))+1; j++){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For N rows of data, you will have a loop index running from 0 to N-1.  You can get the required 'up and down' shape by evaluating `M = min(i, N-1-i)`.  For N = 6, this generates the sequence 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0; for N = 7, it generates 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0.  In a given row of stars, you print `m = 2 * M + 1` stars.  Hence:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static inline int min(int x, int y) { return (x < y) ? x : y; }

int main(void)
{
    int N;
    if (scanf("%d", &N) == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            int m = 2 * min(i, N - 1 - i) + 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                putchar('*');
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The key trick is the expression for `M`.

Note that the code checks for a valid input directly by testing the return value from `scanf()` and indirectly by not printing anything for a zero or negative value for `N`.  It doesn't do a plausibility check on `N` but probably should.

If your compiler doesn't support C99 or C11, you can use a macro in place of the inline function, and declare the loop indexes outside the loops.